# How to enable unknown types during annotation processing in DSL json

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm trying to use [dsl-json](https://github.com/ngs-doo/dsl-json) for (de)serialization in my java project and I'm getting this error during maven compilation:

```
"Property x is referencing unknown type: y which has an unknown part: z. Register custom converter, mark property as ignored or enable unknown types"
```

I can avoid it by putting `@JsonIgnore` on the property/getter, but there are so many properties that I think it will be easier to enable unknow types. How can I do that. I'm using java 8, maven 3.5.0, and eclipse oxygen.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the compiler option `dsljson.unknown = ALLOW` like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArguments>
            <Adsljson.unknown>ALLOW</Adsljson.unknown>
        </compilerArguments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then init the DslJson with the built-in analyzers

```
new DslJson<>(Settings.withRuntime().includeServiceLoader()
```